# How to resolve Skipping acquire of configured file Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Tags: updates

```
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./i18n/Translation-ka_GE' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./i18n/Translation-ka' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

**strong text**

Comment: @Arjun it didn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 1):

In terminal execute the following command

```
sudo grep -i postgresql /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Now edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` using;

```
`sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`
```

and change the line that begins with

`deb https://` to `deb [arch=amd64] https://` and save the file.

Answer (score 0):

Without more contextual information this may not be the answer you are looking for, but I had a similar issue when updating my own box:

`N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://pkg.cloudflare.com/cloudflared focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'`

I cleared this message by navigating to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and deleting the contents of that directory with `rm`.

Note my box is running Ubuntu Server 20.04, and I no longer had need of that repository. Not sure what your circumstances are.